# Writing data on files

Tags: python, matrix, file-writing

I want to write my problem datas from the program into a txt file
for example:

```
m=4
n=2
mat=[[0,1],[2,3],[3,0],[0,1]]
```

I tried to use `file.write()` but I dont know how to write a matrix with this because it only writes string values

Comment: Shouldn't it be `m=4`? Is there some reason the file format has to be text?

Comment: If you created a class that had these items as attributes, you could then use the `pickle` module to save instance of the class very easily. If you want a text format representation, you can specify `protocol=0` when calling `pickle.dump()`.  Encapsulating them in a class isn't a requirement, but doing so would make things a little easier.

Comment: You're right i corected it

Comment: If `m` and `n` are the dimensions of `mat` then they wouldn't need to be specified separately if you used `pickle`—you could just `dump` the `m` variable which would implicitly save that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `numpy` library to save your array and then if you want the values in your program you can load it and use it also you open the txt file and see the values.

as an example:

```
import numpy as np
mtx = [[0,1],[2,3],[3,0],[0,1]]
arr = np.array(mtx)
np.savetxt('mytextarray.txt' , arr , delimiter = ',')
```

then you can load it:

```
arr = np.loadtxt('mytextarray.txt' , delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Is there annother method to make that without numpy?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the `repr()` of your data, and use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it back to Python, but this would be reinventing the proverbial SquaredWheel(tm) when you already have json:

```
import json

data = {
   "m":4,
   "n":2,
   "mat": [[0,1],[2,3],[3,0],[0,1]]
   }

def save_data(filepath, data):
   with open(filepath, "w") as f:
       json.dump(f, data)

def read_data(filepath):
   with open(filepath, "r") as f:
       return json.load(f)
```

This will work out of the box for all "basic" types supported by python's `json` module (string, ints, floats, lists, dicts, tuples, boolean, and the `None` object), and you can provide your own json encoders and decoders if you need to support other types.